# Retrieve Internal attributes(entryUUID) from openldap server

Tags: python-2.7, ldap, openldap

I am trying to retrieve internal attributes from openldap server. More specifically I need to retrieve **entryUUID** attribute of an object. In LDAP, **objectGUID** is being fetched from server but couldn't retrieve similar field from openldap.

**SCOPE_SUBTREE** is being used to retrieve attributes.
Anyone knows way out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'Couldn't' is not a problem description. In this case you got lucky, but in general you can't expect answers to coding problems without providing the code. [tag:active-directory] has nothing to do with it. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: Sometimes you don't get the logic behind. If you don't know, you ask. Thats what I did. You now knew my problem. If you know the editable places, you can suggest editions. I don't think the tags are used indiscriminately. Those are related to problem that I am facing.

Comment: 1. You're supposed to post code if you want help with it. 2. Active Directory isn't an OpenLDAP server. 3. Nobody can know the 'editable places' of code you haven't posted. You're not making sense.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 2):

It was probably downvoted because it is recommended to use this attribute as a means of uniquely identifying an entry. For example,

"'entryUUID' operational
attribute and associated matching rules and syntax.  The attribute
holds a server-assigned Universally Unique Identifier (UUID) for the
object.  Directory clients may use this attribute to distinguish
objects identified by a distinguished name or to locate an object
after renaming."

from the offical Open Ldap [documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4530).

Internal or operational attributes can be requested using '+', which will return operational attributes for a Ldap entry including the entryuuid.

Answer (score 0):

It's an operational attribute, so you have to request it explicitly, or include `"+"` in the attributes to be returned.

However you should not be using this for your own purposes. It's none of your business. It can change across backup/restore, for example.